# Android Composite Widget -Static or Dynamic - Comments

Tags: android

I have a ListView with hundreds of rows sorted A to Z.  I'd like to create a Composite Widget located on the right with TextViews labeled A to Z.  Touching each TextView will filter the ListView and only display records that start with the letter of the TextView.  For example, touching C will filter all rows and only display items that start with the letter C.

I could simply create 26 TextViews labeled A to Z, but I'd like to only create TextViews of letters of items in the ListView.  That is, if there are no items that begin with X, then don't create an X TextView and create TextViews of letters of items in the ListView.  If the items in the ListView are apple, banana and grape, then create three TextViews labled A, B and G.

Can Android support this?  Is this a bad design?  What do you recommend?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can Android support this?

Sure.

> Is this a bad design?

Yes. Your `TextViews` will be too small to be tapped.

> What do you recommend?

Use [standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942421/android-what-does-settextfilterenabled-method-do) [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847763/arrayadapter-and-androidtextfilterenabled) [`ListView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071368/i-have-a-listview-using-a-custom-arraylist-adapter-whats-the-best-way-to-imple) [filtering](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html). There are many more answers here on StackOverflow [referencing the `Filterable` interface](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]+filterable).

Comment: android:textFilterEnabled is the tag you're looking for.